# Displaying a new image for each new section with running table of contents

Tags: beamer, graphics, table-of-contents, formatting

I would like to have the table of contents slide displayed at every `\section{}` however, along with the particular section highlighted (as usual in beamer using `\AtBeginSection[]{...}`), I would like to *display an image to its right* too.

Can anyone tell me how this could be done. Here is a TeX file which will achieve the same but I have done it manually and not with the \AtBeginSection[]{...}` command. Hence I cannot get the other sections to dim out in the usual beamer style. I hope the problem is clear.

```
\documentclass[blue,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\section{New section}
\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
\begin{enumerate}
\item New Section
\item \textcolor{gray}{New New Section}
\item \textcolor{gray}{New New New Section}
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{pic1.png}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some details about this section}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some more details about this section}
\end{frame}
\section{New New section}
\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{gray}{New Section}
\item New New Section
\item \textcolor{gray}{New New New Section}
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{pic2.png}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some details about this section}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some more details about this section}
\end{frame}
\section{New New New section}
\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{gray}{New Section}
\item \textcolor{gray}{New New Section}
\item New New New Section
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{0.3cm}

\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pic3.png}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some details about this section}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some more details about this section}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is how the pages of the Pdf file look] Sorry for the small font, but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `\insertsectionbumber` or `\thesection` are useful:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \begin{columns}
      \column{.5\linewidth}

      \tableofcontents[currentsection]

      \column{.5\linewidth}

      \includegraphics{pic\insertsectionnumber}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A}
\end{frame}

\section{B}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{B}
\end{frame}

\section{C}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{C}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `if` statement to control the display of images at given sections.

### Code

```
\documentclass[blue,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe} % provides images used in this example

\begin{document}
\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
  \begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]

  \hfill
  \ifnum \thesection=1
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image-a}
  \else
  \ifnum \thesection=2
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image-b}
  \else
  \ifnum \thesection=3
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{image-c}
  \fi\fi\fi

  \end{frame}
}

\section{New section}

\begin{frame}{some details about this section}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some more details about this section}
\end{frame}

\section{New New section}

\begin{frame}{some details about this section}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some more details about this section}
\end{frame}

\section{New New New section}

\begin{frame}{some details about this section}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{some more details about this section}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]