# Picture next to the table of contents (TOC) in Beamer correctly aligned vertically

Tags: beamer, graphics, table-of-contents, minipage

I want to place picture in [Beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX)) presentation next to the table of contents (TOC), specifically on the right side of the TOC.

I know that there are several questions about similar or even identical problems, e.g.:

1. [Beamer - Put a picture right of the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95178/44382)
2. [How to split a frame (of beamer) into 2 parts (minipage) side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26836/44382)
3. [Displaying a new image for each new section with running table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146455/44382)

but the posted answers doesn't work well because as a result I get TOC lowered (see [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xaU4.png) below).

This is answer from [1st linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95182/44382):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[t][0.6\textheight]{0.6\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\section{A section with a name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{A longer section name, ....................}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{another section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{a medium long section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

this is the result:

[image: Example with minipages]

It seems to work well, but if you remove `minipages` like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A section with a name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{A longer section name, ....................}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{another section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{a medium long section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

you get this:

[image: Example without minipages]

If you put above screenshots side by side, like this:

[image: Side by side comparison of both examples]

you can clearly see that suggested solution *lowers TOC*. I want to place image next to TOC *without lowering TOC* and *without absolute image positioning* (because I want to be able to change `aspectratio` of the presentation without modifying hard coded image offsets).

How can I do this?

Comment: The [t] option refers to the first baseline, which for an image is the same as the bottom,  Use \raisebox to align images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start.

It works as second section etc... is not too long else it would hit the picture. In that case you only need to use a suitable `\rightskip` setting (or whatever works with beamer class to temporarily set right margin; I suspect rightskip will not necessarily play well but I have not tested as the code works fine enough with given example) and push the picture by a `\rlap` into available space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\DeclareRobustCommand\PICINTOC{}%

\newcommand\MYPICINTOC
  {\hfill
   \smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\PICINTOC\string\MYPICINTOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A section with a name\PICINTOC}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{A longer section name, ....................}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{another section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{a medium long section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clever!  Get the TOC itself to write the picture.  That way it doesn't matter what sort of offsets Beamers throws in.

Comment: @JohnKormylo but main defect is that the picture reserves no space... for this one would need more advanced tricks and possibly  to check beamer code for the TOC, which I wanted to not have to do ;-) ...

Comment: I did check the beamer code.  It didn't help.